# Group by and check value for that group in hive/sql

Tags: hive, group-by, hiveql

I have a table with below data.

```
id start     current
1  today     True
2  yesterday False
1  Monday    False
3  yesterday True
3  Monday    False
4  today     
4  Tuesday   
5  Wednesday True
6  Friday    
6  Monday    
7  Sunday    True
7  Tuesday
```

I want to check how many ids contains all nulls in the current column and print that count.

I thought of using group by id and select ids where current is null but its not giving the appropriate count. I wan to count only if all the rows for particular id contains current as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31f6e/12

```
select count(distinct start)
from 
(
select start,max(case when current is not null then 1 else 0 end) mt
from data
group by start)a where mt=0
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, find all the id(s) whose `MAX(current)` is NULL.
- Then, simply **count** them out.

Try the following query (will work in MySQL):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IF(derived_t.max_current IS NULL, 
                         derived_t.id, 
                         NULL)) AS ids_with_all_null
(
SELECT id, MAX(current) as max_current 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY id
) AS derived_t
```

Comment: I dont want to get the count of the null ids, i want to get count of  distinct ids which have all the current values as nulls, in the above table the id 6 and four contains 2 rows each and current column value for these two rows is null, so i want to get 4,6 as my output to the above table. To be more precise, i want ids of where current is null for all the entries for that id.

Comment: @shashank it will get you count of all those id(s) only which have all of their current field as null. please run and check. If you need more explanation on how it works, let me know - I will update

Answer (score 0):

You can use exists-clause for that. "Find count of individual `id`'s which do not have rows that have value of `current` other than `NULL`"

```
select count(distinct d.id)
from data d
where not exists (
  select *
  from data d2
  where d2.id=d.id and d2.current is not null
)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31f6e/1)

Comment: You have the mysql-tag in the question